# JQuery not working on Live

Tags: jquery, html

i am using Styleshop HTML template from Mojo Theme DEMO link download

```
http://wintechserver.com/mojo/styleshop/html/product.html
```

I have implemented the same code on a dynamic website everything is working fine on Local machine but the am getting some Jquery error on the page mentioned below:

> http://freekishopping.in/store/product/lg-g2/

The Image Holder is not working Problem both demo and live site are working same jquery version but the live site i not working fine.

can anyone tell me what is the issue

Comment: please post your code here.

Comment: @Krishna i dont know where is the problem so dont know which snippet to post

Comment: Well the problem is easily detected by viewing the Javascript console, it's on line 70 in custom.js, there are also another error, but you can take a look at that

Comment: i dont know anything about jquery can ay1 tell me what i have to do to make it working

Answer (score 0):

Seems that JQuery itself works fine on your site. but your custom.js has an error

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

on line 21. If it has syntax error, that it won't be executed.

Comment: Can you tell me what i have to do to make ti working ?